# How to embed/add jquery and bootstrap on the same page

Tags: jquery

How can you embed/add jQuery and bootstrap on the same page, at the same time? should you use the Microsoft or Google API link? I've tried to integrate these to work with bootstrap and jQuery. but unfortunately it said:

> "warning, some of your code has been removed"

Answer (score 0):

Use a script editor web part to avoid this message. Add this web part to the page.

In the script just add your script references like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="location/to/your/script"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="another/location/to/your/script"></script>
```

Comment: Allright.. sounds as a good idea. The next question is, should I then paste the bootstrap an jquery code inside this script editor webpart, or should I then do it in the normal editor?

Comment: Yes you can add your code into this editor between script tags `<script type="text/javascript">//some code</script>`. My preference would be to add a reference to a JavaScript file in your Site Assets library, and add your JavaScript to that file.